# C++ Disposing Textures

Tags: c++, memory-management, sdl

Recently, I've asked in a code review if my code was causing any pointer related issues. They mentioned that I had problems with my dispose method. Basically, I'm disposing textures from a texture map, by cleaning the texture at the ID given to the method. So I would like to ask you if now, I'm disposing correctly my texture, and if there's a better way to do it.

```
void TextureManager::freeTexture(std::string id){

    std::map<std::string, SDL_Texture*>::iterator it = m_textureMap.find(id);

    std::cout << "Disposing texture : [ID==" << id << "] [MemoryAdress==" << it->second << "] : \n";

    if (it == m_textureMap.end())
    {
        LOGERROR("ERROR : Invalid ID : cannot dispose texture");
        return;
    }

    SDL_DestroyTexture(it->second);
    std::cout << "--> Destroyed !";

    m_textureMap.erase(id);
    std::cout << " --> Erased from TextureMap !\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Link to the previous question for reference: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/87367/39810

Comment: I know ! I was the one who posted it !

Comment: Hehe, yes, it wasn't for you, but for the others looking at this question `;)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it is fine. `erase()` will get rid of the `<key,value>` pair indexed by the id.

A tiny optimization here would be calling `erase()` with the iterator `it` instead of the `id` string. This should avoid a second lookup, since the iterator already contains the relevant information `map` need to remove the item. You can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) that `erase()` operates on keys or iterators.

Also, pass your `id` string by const reference, since the method does not need a copy of the string. E.g.:

```
void TextureManager::freeTexture(const std::string & id) { /* ... */ }
                                 ^^^^^             ^
```

This is a very long and error prone line:

> ```
> std::map<std::string, SDL_Texture*>::iterator
> ```

You should `typedef` the map type or use `auto` if targeting C++11.

Typedefing map somewhere:

```
// In the header file somewhere...
typedef std::map<std::string, SDL_Texture*> TextureMap;

// Then it is a little simpler to use:
TextureMap::iterator it = map.find(...);
```

Or just use `auto` if you can:

```
auto it = map.find(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a map of naked/raw/bald pointers-to-textures. When you remove an element from the map you must call a C-like function to destroy the texture.

A more C++-like way to do it would be to:

1. Define a class whose destructor destroys the texture ...

   ```
   class Texture
   {
       SDL_Texture* m_ptr;
   public:
       Texture(SDL_Texture* ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}
       ~Texture()
       {
           SDL_DestroyTexture(m_ptr);
           std::cout << "--> Destroyed !";
       }
       // plus other methods to use m_ptr
       // and/or overload the pointer operator to
       // let people use this class like a pointer.
   };
   ```

   ... and [disable the copy-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6077143/49942) and assignment operator for this class.
2. Change the type of your m_textureMap so that it [contains smart pointers](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#container-of-smart-ptr) to instances of the `Texture` class ... so that the smart-pointer deletes the Texture instance (which deletes its SDL_Texture pointer) when it's removed from the map and no longer referenced elsewhere, and/or when the map is destroyed.