# Creating an optimized, fully functional TextureManager in SDL

Tags: c++, memory-management, sdl

After I've discussed pointer semantics with Loki Astari previously, I finally managed to code the TextureManager class using `auto_pointer`s. But the problem is that I need to pass an `SDL_Renderer` object to my class' constructor as an auto_ptr. But the object I want to pass is a **raw** pointer.

How should I do it? Also, I'm not so sure about the `aout_pointers` I've written. Can you help me, please?

**TextureManager.h**

```
#pragma once //using visual C++

#include <unordered_map>
#include "Texture.h"
#include <memory>

/**
    This class helps the user to manage large 
    amount of texture at the same time (disposing them, setting 
    their color, their renderer, ...). The dispose method of this class 
    should be called before the end of the program (there will be no issues
    if it is not called : the destrctor of the TextureManager class will call
    the destructor of the @Texture class ! But it is better to call it, since
    it will release all ressources when you want !).This class contains a dynamic
    array, so the user can add @Texture pointers threw out the programs
    evolution.
*/

typedef std::unordered_map<int, Texture*> atlasType;//cannot use auto_ptr in STL container !

class TextureManager
{
public:
    TextureManager(std::auto_ptr<SDL_Renderer> pRenderer);
    ~TextureManager();

    void setRenderer(std::auto_ptr<SDL_Renderer> pRenderer);
    bool LoadFromFile(unsigned int ID, const char* fileName);

    bool unloadTexture(unsigned int ID);
    void dispose();

    Texture& getTexture(unsigned int ID);
    Texture getTextureCopy(unsigned int ID);

private:
    std::auto_ptr<SDL_Renderer> m_pRenderer;
    atlasType m_textureAtlas;
};
```

**TextureManager.cpp**

```
#include "TextureManager.h"


TextureManager::TextureManager(std::auto_ptr<SDL_Renderer> pRenderer)
    : m_pRenderer(pRenderer)
{}

TextureManager::~TextureManager(){
    dispose();
}

void TextureManager::dispose(){
    for (atlasType::iterator it = m_textureAtlas.begin(); it != m_textureAtlas.end(); ++it){
        delete (it->second);
    }
    m_textureAtlas.clear();
}


bool TextureManager::unloadTexture(unsigned int ID){
    Texture *pTempTexture = m_textureAtlas[ID];

    if (!pTempTexture)
        return false;

    delete pTempTexture;//dispose texture
    pTempTexture = nullptr;
    m_textureAtlas.erase(ID);

    return true;
}

Texture& TextureManager::getTexture(unsigned int ID){
    return *(m_textureAtlas[ID]);
}

Texture TextureManager::getTextureCopy(unsigned int ID){
    return *(m_textureAtlas[ID]);
}

bool TextureManager::LoadFromFile(unsigned int ID, const char* fileName){
    Texture *pTexture = m_textureAtlas[ID];

    if (pTexture == nullptr){
        pTexture = new Texture();
        pTexture->setRenderer(m_pRenderer.get());//Texture uses raw pointer;

        m_textureAtlas[ID] = pTexture;//will be deleted in dispose;
    }
    if (!pTexture->LoadFromFile(fileName))
        return false;

    return true;
}

void TextureManager::setRenderer(std::auto_ptr<SDL_Renderer> pRenderer){
    m_pRenderer = pRenderer;
}
```

Here's where I can not call the constructor (raw pointer <-> `auto_ptr`):

```
/* ......Declarations........... */

SDL_Renderer * m_pRenderer = nullptr;

/* etc..........*/

m_pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_pWindow, -1, 0);


/*Trying to create TextureManager*/


m_textureManager = TextureManager(m_pRenderer);//fail to compile : is not of type auto_ptr<SDL_Renderer> ! what shall I do ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make you wrapper usabel as a rendorer:

```
class CWindowWrap
{
    public:
        operator SDL_Window*() {return window;}
        ....
};

// Now when you have a CWindowWrap you can use it anywhere an 
// SDL_Window* can be used. The compiler sees there is an 
// automatic conversion from CWindowWrap to a SDL_Window* and
// calls this function to do the conversion.
```

Comment: thanks, I wil add this to my code, and I think that it will be finished !!!! No more textureManaging !!!!

Answer (score 2):

### You don't need a texture copy.

```
Texture& getTexture(unsigned int ID);
// Texture getTextureCopy(unsigned int ID);
```

This works:

```
Texture&  t1 = tm.getTexture(1);  // Gets a reference.
Texture   t2 = tm.getTexture(2);  // Gets a reference but because t2
                                  // is an object copies it from the
                                  // original into `t2`
```

### auto_ptr is deprecated

```
std::auto_ptr<SDL_Renderer>
```

Prefer the modern version `std::unique_ptr` it understands move semantics.

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Renderer, TypeThatKnowsHowToDeleteSDLRendor>  renderer;
```

Also `std::unique_ptr` and `std::auto_ptr` just call `delete` on the pointer. I am betting that the SDL library has a special function to delete render objects. In which case you need to add a class that knows what function to call.

Also `std::unqiue_ptr` can be used in containers:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<int, Texture*> atlasType;//cannot use auto_ptr in STL container !
```

But you don't even need to be using pointers. Texture is **not** polymorphic. Just create the object in the container (not the pointer).

```
std::unordered_map<int, Texture>  AtlasType;
```

### Naming conventions.

It is usall to give User defined types an initial capitol letter. It is usual to give methods and member variables an initial lower case letter.

```
std::unordered_map<int, Texture>  AtlasType;
             //                   ^  Its a user defined type.
AtlasType                         textureAtlas;
             //                   ^ its an addressable object.
```

### Prefer the new range based for

```
for (atlasType::iterator it = m_textureAtlas.begin(); it != m_textureAtlas.end(); ++it){
    delete (it->second);
}
```

As mentioned last time. Prefer `auto`, prefer std::begin/std::end over method calls. and prefer range based for over all of them:

```
//
for (auto it = std::begin(m_textureAtlas); it != std::end(m_textureAtlas); ++it){
    delete (it->second);
}

//
for(auto item: m_textureAtlas) {
    delete item.second;
}

//
std::for_each(std::begin(m_textureAtlas), std::end(m_textureAtlas),
               [](AtlasType::value_type& v){delete v.second;});
```

### Compilation Failure:

```
 m_textureManager = TextureManager(m_pRenderer);
                               //  ^^^^^^^^^^^ that is not an auto_ptr

 // You have to create the auto_ptr object.
 std::auto_ptr<SDL_Renderer>   rend(m_pRenderer)
 m_textureManager = TextureManager(rend);
```

Note. When you give up ownership of the object you should not be using it from the original pointer again. The only way to access the render object should not be through the `TextureManager` that owns it. If you have kept another pointer to the renderer that you are cheating ownership semantics.

### Writting a shard render object

```
class CRendWrap
{
    public:
        CRendWrap(SDL_Window* w, int x, int y)
            : SDL_CreateRenderer(w, x, y)
        {}
        ~CRendWrap()
        {
            if (rend != nullptr) {
                SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
            }
        }
        // Disable Copy
        CRendWrap(CRendWrap const&)             = delete;
        CRendWrap& operator=(CRendWrap const&)  = delete;
        // Allow Move
        CRendWrap(CRendWrap&& move)
            : rend(nullptr)
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(rend, move.rend);
        }
        CRendWrap& operator=(CRendWrap&& move)
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(rend, move.rend);
        }
    prviate:
        SDL_Renderer*   rend;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<CRendWrap>   CRender;

// Usage.
CRender  renderer = std::make_shared<CRendWrap>(win, 10, 20);
```

Comment: Actually, there's no "type" which knows how to delete the Renderer ! So, as you said, I have to create a special class to destroy it! The SDL library provides a function called SDL_DestroyRenderer(SDL_Renderer renderer);

Comment: Thank by the way; I started C++ just a month ago; Now I think I won't make stupid semantic errors with pointers ! Also, 1) would it be a good idea to use a shared_ptr to represent the SDL_Renderer ? 2) If I do not use Texture pointers, will Texture instantly be deleted when I remove them from the map ?

Comment: 2) If I do not use Texture pointers, will Texture instantly be deleted when I remove them from the map ? 3) When you call 'auto', will the type be replaced at compile time ? 4) I agree with what you said at the end, but there's a little problem ! I need to make that auto_ptr decleration in a method called init() : when my program will reach the end of the scope, the ptr will be deleted and I'll have a null renderer in TextureManager! Thanks by the way, I started C++ a month ago, and you really helped me!

Comment: 1) If the renderer is used by many objects then yes a shared pointer is a good idea. **BUT** there is not way to a custom deleter. So you will need to write a quick wrapper class. So create a `CRenderer` class that holds an `SDL_Renderer` and correctly deletes it in the destructor. Then you can put the `CRenderer` in a shared_ptr.

Comment: 2) Yes. When you erase the member from the container or call clear on the container or let the container be destroyed. Then the destructor of the Texture object is immediately called.

Comment: 3) Yes. The keyword auto means: Compiler work out the type for me.

Comment: 4) Use std::unique_ptr instead of std::auto_ptr. Most of your problems will go away.

Comment: Ok, can you help me please to implement CRenderer ? The functions to be called are SDL_DestroyRenderer(SDL_Renderer * pRenderer), and to init a renderer, you must call m_pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(SDL_Window * , int, int); Finnally it shoul be declared as the folowing SDL_Renderer* renderer;

Comment: About  4) it just won't change it to nullptr; nothing else to do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23160/discussion-between-mattmatt-and-loki-astari).

Comment: And what are the exact properties of a shared_ptr ? Can I call it from another class, from another .cpp ? If so, how ?

Comment: Also, what is the exact purpose of a move constructor apart from making my program running faster ?

Comment: One more little thing : can I wrap the SDL_WIndow too ?

Comment: OK, I made an CWindow wrapper; there's just a little problem : I would like the CRendererWrapper class to construct a Renderer form a CWindowWrapper class : only problem, how can you  get the raw pointer SDL_Window* from CWindowWrapper (SDL_CreateWindow takes a raw pointer in argument) ? Shall I make getRawPtr() method returning a Window raw pointer ? Help please !!!